# What are the pros and cons of Relays and Transistors

Tags: switch

I heard that transistors have two main purposes, amplifying signals and switching on and off very quickly.
I also heard that relays can acts as switches. Relays rely on a magnetic force pulling the switch of another circuit on and off.
What are the advantages and disadvantages of relays and transistors, and in which cases should wae use both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that relays switch a **different** circuit while transistors switch the circuit that **the transistor is in**.